# How to expose REST services to internal and external parties?

Tags: rest

I have couple of modules which communicate internally through REST services. Now I want to expose some of the REST services to third parties. Though I have provided authentication JWS but still have some doubt:

1. What design should I follow to expose only few REST services to third parties
2. In case if I need to remove any third party exposed REST service, my current application with communication among the modules should still work.
3. Do we have any framework available to expose few REST services to third parties.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this would be by deploying next to your already existing app (let's call it *internal*) the very same app, but on a different port (let's call this one *public*). Your REST service should communicate just as before, through the internal one; however you can add an exception in the firewall for that new port so that the public rest service can be accessible by third parties. You could then have an access control policy that states which endpoints (REST services) can't also be accessed from the public app.

Of course specifying which technologies you're using would probably get you more tailored solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I also had this solution in mind. But wanted to know will any API gateway be of any help? I am using Spring-Hibernate